# Angular 2 create Directive for dragging elements

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I'm trying to create a **Dicrective** in Angular 2 that allows the user to drag the HTML Element by the x position. 
I wrote this pseudo code of how I think it might work, but am not experienced enough with directives to know what the right `HostListener` parameter would be.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Renderer, HostListener } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
    selector: '[draggable]'
})

export class DragDirective {

    constructor(private el: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer) { }

    @HostListener('move')
    moveElement(xpos:number) {
        this.renderer.setElementProperty(this.el.nativeElement, 'xpos', xpos);
    }
}
```

More specifically I'm trying to use this to move [Tabs](https://justindujardin.github.io/ng2-material/#/components/tabs) from [Angular 2 Material](https://material.angular.io/) for with I would also have to update its index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i did it using [jQuery ui's sortable](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/) function.

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';


@Directive({
    selector: '[draggable]'
})

export class DragDirective {

    constructor() {
        $(function() {
            (<any>$("#sortable-tabs")).sortable();
        });
    }
}
```

The (< any >$("#sortable-tabs")) is there because otherwise it would throw an error while compiling that the sortable function is not defined